# How to build only a few packages from a repository, instead of all?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case I am trying to use the Universal Robots package and the robotiq grippers package. These two packages I am installing them from source into my catkin workspace. But, these packages are very wide in the sense that I only need the description from one of the arms and a specific gripper. I want to avoid excessive computing when I run catkin build command tool. I am pretty new to ROS, so is this recommendable or should I install the full package?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350488/how-to-build-only-a-few-packages-from-a-repository,-instead-of-all?/) by [lms95](https://answers.ros.org/users/53716/lms95/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I only need the description from one of the arms and a specific gripper.

You'll need to make sure to not remove any part of the repository you cloned which is used by the package(s) you are interested in, but other than that you should be able to either:

- remove the directories containing the packages you're not interested in, or
- place a `CATKIN_IGNORE` file in those directories

Both will cause the packages to no longer be built, nor found by any ROS tool. Not even in the `src` space of your workspace.

And a quick comment:

> These two packages I am installing them from source into my catkin workspace. But, these packages are very wide in the sense that I only need the description from one of the arms and a specific gripper

where you write "package", you most of the time seem to actually be referring to the *repository*. Repositories contain packages. A collection of packages is not also called "a package".

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-25**:
And as always:

> These two packages I am installing them from source

only build things from source if you really have to.

The "issue" you are running into is one of the reasons why from-source builds should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps you can use the `catkin build` command instead of `catkin_make`. catkin build allows for building individual packages via `catkin build PKG_NAME` to prevent rebuilding all. But this only works well when you are constantly building a small number of packages. If your problem is in reverse, in that you want to build all except a few packages, what gvdhoorn said is accurate, adding a `touch CATKIN_IGNORE` in the package directory will exclude it from future rebuilds.

Another method is to build all the static packages in one workspace and all the packages that need constant rebuilding in another workspace. Then, you can add an alias so that you are able to source both directories simultaneously

`alias source_everything="source ws_1/devel/setup.bash && source ws_2/devel/setup.bash --extend"`

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [hashirzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53034/hashirzahir/) with karma: 228 on 2020-04-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1